# How to convert yaml file to json in Flask application?

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests, yaml

Is there a way to convert yaml textual data(from python requests on Flask) to json format, or at least exract key value pairs.
config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: confmap
data:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  #randominline
  key3: "string_value"
  key4: value4
...
```

I am using python request to get this yaml file from http:

```
result = requests.get(URL, verify=False)
print(result.text) #prints text from yaml files.
```

Is there a way now to convert this textual formated yaml file to json format, or at least to extract key value?

Comment: Thank you! I will try, but should work.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're working in Python already, you can read in the YAML file using [PyYAML's](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) `yaml.load()`, which will give you a nested Python structure of dicts and lists, as appropriate. You can then use `json.dumps()` (available in core Python's [json package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)) to write the result to a string, and write the string to a file. If desired, that string can then be written to a text file:

```
from yaml import load as yaml_load
from json import dumps as json_dump

with open(source_yaml_path, 'r') as source_file:
    pystruct = yaml_load(source_file.read())

json_string = json_dump(pystruct)

with open(output_json_path, 'w') as dest_file:
    dest_file.write(json_string)
```

(Obviously, you'll need to supply your own values for `source_yaml_path` and `output_json_path`.) The `pystruct` object in the intermediate can be parsed if you want the program to do something with the YAML file other than converting the format.

Comment: I don't have source_yaml_path, but requests towards http(containing yaml file)

Comment: defining text_data = url_response.text , and your code worked perfectly. Ty so much :) !